# How can I change Debug icon in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to change debug icon in VS 2019. Do you have any information on this subject?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are [off-topic at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You could start at [Visual Studio Extensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompile Visual Studio with the debug icon of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. Go to the Project properties
2. Under Application tab change the default icon to your own
3. Build the project

Comment: The OP wants to change an icon in the Visual Studio program, not a program that they have written.